# Android: Can not replace fragment create in activity onCreate() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have trouble why learning Android fragments. 
In my app I have one activity with 3 fragments. Each fragment is to replace previous after some user action. My main xml layout is simple FrameLayout with ID 'container'. What I do in MainActivity onCreate() method is adding default fragment to container:

```
public class HolderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....

        FragmentList listFragment = new FragmentList();

        // Add the fragment to the 'container'
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, listFragment).commit();
```

Initial screen works just fine.
Then I add other fragment, based on button click:

```
        // Go to settings fragment
        FragmentSettings mFragmentSettings = new FragmentSettings();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragmentSettings).commit();
```

The problem is that when I click needed button App doesn't replace fragments, it just adds new fragment over the old one, so they collapse. Could You please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:
When I try to use *getSupportFragmentManager()* in my *onOptionsItemSelected* method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        // Go to settings fragment
        FragmentSettings mFragmentSettings = new FragmentSettings();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, mFragmentSettings).commit();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I get this error:
"The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentSettings)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a supportFragmentManager and then the normal FragmentManager?

`getSupportFragmentManager()` and `getFragmentManager()`.

If you're using `ActionBarActivity`, then use support one. If `Activity` then the normal one.

Comment: I use second(replace) method within `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {` method. And when I call `getSupportFragmentManager` i get an error on **replace** saying that it is not applicable with these arguments.

Comment: @Vla Post the code that you used and the full error message.

Comment: Updated my post with details

Comment: @Vla FragmentSettings class must extend Fragment or any of it's derivative classes.

Comment: My FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment

Comment: @Vla that's because `PreferenceFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`. supportFragmentManager expects a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Either switch to using the normal fragmentManager or use something else than a `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: Now I got it completely :) Thank You much, that is working now!